# KendoUI para de funcionar ao separar AngularJS num arquivo .js

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Estou tentando criar um simples projeto de KendoUI + AngularJS. Quando eu uso o código abaixo, tudo funciona normal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <a class="offline-button" href="../index.html">Back</a>
    <div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
        <div class="demo-section k-content" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <div class="box-col">
                <h4>Set Value</h4>
                <p>
                    <input kendo-numeric-text-box k-min="0" k-max="100" k-ng-model="value" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-col">
                <h4>Set Value</h4>
                <div kendo-slider k-min="0" k-max="100" k-ng-model="value"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-col">
                <h4>Result</h4>
                Value: {{value}}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        angular.module("KendoDemos", ["kendo.directives"]);
        function MyCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.value = 50;
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mas quando tento separar o código do AngularJS num arquivo `.js` separado (como mostrado no final), a página para de funcionar (em relação do kendoUI):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/kendo/2014.2.716/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app/itensApp.js"></script> <!--ADDED-->
</head>
<body>
    <a class="offline-button" href="../index.html">Back</a>
    <div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
        <div class="demo-section k-content" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <div class="box-col">
                <h4>Set Value</h4>
                <p>
                    <input kendo-numeric-text-box k-min="0" k-max="100" k-ng-model="value" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="box-col">
                <h4>Set Value</h4>
                <div kendo-slider k-min="0" k-max="100" k-ng-model="value"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-col">
                <h4>Result</h4>
                Value: {{value}}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Scripts/itensApp.js

```
(function() {
    var itensApp = angular.module('KendoDemos', ["kendo.directives"]);
}());
```

Console:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/areq?p0=MyCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:10642/scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js:6:450
    at xb (http://localhost:10642/scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js:18:360)
    at Ra (http://localhost:10642/scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js:18:447)
    at http://localhost:10642/scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js:66:96
    at http://localhost:10642/scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js:53:14
    at q (http://localhost:10642/scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js:7:386)
    at J (http://localhost:10642/scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js:52:382)
    at f (http://localhost:10642/scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js:46:399)
    at f (http://localhost:10642/scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js:46:416) angular.min.js:89
GET http://localhost:10642/scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/angular.min.js.map 404 (Not Found)
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Murphy, tente dar títulos descritivos às suas perguntas, "Ajuda com projeto simples" não significa muita coisa. Fiz a melhor interpretação que pude, fique à vontade para ajustar.

Comment: Obrigado Brasofilo.

Comment: Murphy, no segundo caso, onde está a declaração do seu `Controller`? No console do browser é exibido algum erro?

Comment: Wakim, fiz update colocando os dados do console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei o erro (e era muito simples na verdade).

Esqueci de adicionar o controller no module. Quando estava tudo na página (module e controller) ok.

Quando resolvi passar para um .js separado, esqueci de adicionar o controller no module explicitamente.

O arquivo itensApp.js deve ficar assim para funcionar:

```
(function () {

    var KendoDemos = angular.module('KendoDemos', ['kendo.directives']);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.value = 50;
    }

    KendoDemos.$inject = ['kendo.directives'];

    angular.module('KendoDemos').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

}());
```

Obrigado e espero que ajude mais alguém desatento como eu.